# Installing Graphviz on Os X 10.5.8

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I'm trying to install Graphviz 2.14.1 on osX 10.5.8
I installed Graphviz from the Universal Binary here:

```
http://www.ryandesign.com/graphviz/  

$ svn co https://networkx.lanl.gov/svn/pygraphviz/trunk pygraphviz  

 - Fingerprint: 43:8e:fa:75:00:60:67:07:fd:04:3c:e7:bf:25:86:fd:66:b3:f6:cb  
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? t  
A    pygraphviz/pygraphviz  
A    pygraphviz/pygraphviz/graphviz.i  
A    pygraphviz/pygraphviz/graphviz.py  
A    pygraphviz/pygraphviz/tests  
A    pygraphviz/pygraphviz/tests/graph.txt  
A    pygraphviz/pygraphviz/tests/attributes.txt  
A    pygraphviz/pygraphviz/tests/__init__.py  
A    pygraphviz/pygraphviz/tests/test.py  
A    pygraphviz/pygraphviz/tests/layout_draw.txt  
A    pygraphviz/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c  
A    pygraphviz/pygraphviz/__init__.py  
A    pygraphviz/pygraphviz/release.py  
A    pygraphviz/pygraphviz/agraph.py  
A    pygraphviz/INSTALL.txt  
A    pygraphviz/doc  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/contents.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/examples.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/static  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/static/contents.png  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/static/navigation.png  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/static/sphinxdoc.css  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/static/empty.txt  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/tutorial.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/conf.py  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/install.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/download.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/reference  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/reference/news.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/reference/credits.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/reference/related.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/reference/api_notes.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/reference/history.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/reference/agraph.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/reference/legal.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/reference/faq.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/reference/index.rst  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/templates  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/templates/layout.html  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/templates/indexsidebar.html  
A    pygraphviz/doc/source/templates/index.html  
A    pygraphviz/doc/sphinxext  
A    pygraphviz/doc/sphinxext/only_directives.py  
A    pygraphviz/doc/Makefile  
A    pygraphviz/setup.py  
A    pygraphviz/setup_egg.py  
A    pygraphviz/setup_extra.py  
A    pygraphviz/MANIFEST.in  
A    pygraphviz/README.txt  
A    pygraphviz/examples  
A    pygraphviz/examples/miles.py  
A    pygraphviz/examples/simple.py  
A    pygraphviz/examples/star.py  
A    pygraphviz/examples/django_simple.py  
A    pygraphviz/examples/subgraph.py  
A    pygraphviz/examples/attributes.py  
A    pygraphviz/examples/miles_dat.txt.gz  
A    pygraphviz/setup.cfg  
 U   pygraphviz  
Checked out revision 1947.  
Bryan@bryan-wheelocks-macbook-pro-15 Tue Dec 21 07:25:18 ~/Downloads   
$ cd pygraphviz/  
Bryan@bryan-wheelocks-macbook-pro-15 Tue Dec 21 07:25:22 ~/Downloads/pygraphviz   
$ python setup.py install  
Trying pkg-config  
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found  
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found  
Trying dotneato-config  
Failed to find dotneato-config  

Your graphviz installation could not be found.  

Either the graphviz package is missing on incomplete  
(binary packages graphviz-dev or graphviz-devel missing?).    

If you think your installation is correct you will need to manually  
change the include_path and library_path variables in setup.py to  
point to the correct locations of your graphviz installation.  

The current setting of library_path and include_path is:  
library_path=None  
include_path=None  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "setup.py", line 78, in <module>  
    raise OSError,"Error locating graphviz."  
OSError: Error locating graphviz.
```

Here is the path to Graphviz:

$ ls -la /usr/local/lib/

```
drwxrwxr-x   40 root   wheel     1360 Dec 21 06:22 graphviz
```

$ python setup.py install --library_path /usr/local/lib/graphviz/

```
Trying pkg-config  
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found  
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found  
Trying dotneato-config  
Failed to find dotneato-config  

Your graphviz installation could not be found.  

Either the graphviz package is missing on incomplete  
(binary packages graphviz-dev or graphviz-devel missing?).    

If you think your installation is correct you will need to manually  
change the include_path and library_path variables in setup.py to  
point to the correct locations of your graphviz installation.  

The current setting of library_path and include_path is:  
library_path=None  
include_path=None  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "setup.py", line 78, in <module>  
    raise OSError,"Error locating graphviz."  
OSError: Error locating graphviz.
```

I was unsuccessful in finding the binary packages graphviz-dev or graphviz-devel

What do I need to do to get this installed?

Comment: This is more suited to SuperUser

Comment: The binary is at `/usr/local/bin/dot`

Answer (score 22):

It seems like you are missing the "pkg-config" package. You can install it with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

> brew install pkg-config

Comment: In my case pkg-config was installed but it was still giving error. Linking again solved it.
`brew unlink pkg-config && brew link pkg-config`

Answer (score 9):

2.14.1 is a very old version of graphviz.  You may have better success using the official OS X installer package for 2.26 (at this writing) [here](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_macos.php).  Then you will likely need to edit the pygraphiz `setup.py` to use the proper `library_path` and `include_path`.  Most likely you will need to uncomment the `/usr/local/lib/graphviz` and `usr/local/include/graphviz` versions but use `ls /usr/local` to find out for sure.

On the other hand, with so many dependent libraries and packages involved, this is a perfect case for using a 3rd-party package manager like `MacPorts` which will manage all of the dependencies for you and allow you to easily update as new releases become available.  Once you have installed the [base MacPorts files](http://www.macports.org/install.php), you can install it all with:

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
#   either
$ sudo port install py26-pygraphviz   # with MacPorts python2.6
#   ... or 
$ sudo port install py27-pygraphviz   # with MacPorts python2.7
```

Answer (score 2):

As Ned said,

1. Locate your setup.py file for graphviz. In my case, it was located at `/Users/*my_username*/build/pygraphviz/setup.py`
2. Finally, uncomment the lines corresponding to the Mac OSX paths for `library_path` and `include_path`. These are the lines containing: `/usr/local/lib/graphviz` and `usr/local/include/graphviz`